# Fixed position div with maximum z-index still shows behind contentplaceholder content

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I have an error dialog in a master page that is inside a ContentTemplate, which is inside an UpdatePanel. The error dialog is a user control (ascx) with a div and a label in it. The div with the relevant bits looks like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanelContent" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div>
        <err:ctrlError ID="error1" runat="server" Visible="true" />
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The error dialog looks like this:

```
<div class="divError" visible="false" runat="server" id="div">    
    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

I have a requirement to have the error dialog appear centered on the screen rather than inline, so I set the styles of the div surrounding the label to have a fixed position. The styles now look like this:

```
.divError
{
    border: thin groove #808080;
    background-color: #F7F6F3;
    clip: rect(10px, 10px, 10px, 10px);
    color: #FF0000;
    width:500px;
    min-height:50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

No matter what I set the z-index to, the contents of the divError div show behind the contents of the contentplaceholder. Here is a link to an example with the z-index set to 2147483647.

[image: Screen shot of div in F12 tools]

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stole some code from a personal project when I did this years ago, and it seems that the div needed a display element to work.  I also dropped that clip element, since I have no idea what it does. The style now looks like this:

```
.divError
{
    border: thin groove #808080;
    position: fixed;
    color: #FF0000;
    z-index: 3000;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 200px;
    left: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

That works.

Answer (score 1):

**Your question:** Why would this happen?

**A:** Because `.divError` is in a stacking context and the root of that stacking context has a `z-index` (*calculated* or *explicitly declared*) lower than the root of the stacking context of the rest of the content that is 'over' `.divError`.

If you want to know how to 'solve' this, the DOM tree leading to and surrounding the `updPanelContent` and positioning and z-index applied to those elements is needed.